# Object back from pointer

Tags: pointers, object, qstring

```
void show(QString *s){
   //Here I want to show the value of the QString.
}
```

How can I do that??

I'd be glad if you could help me.

Comment: What do you mean by 'show the value' - pop up a dialog? convert to a `char*`? Something else?

Comment: Are you just asking how to de-reference the pointer? In that case use the `->` operator (assuming this is C++) - see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you're asking - see my comments.

Maybe this will help?

Check out [toAscii()](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qstring.html#toAscii), [toLatin1()](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qstring.html#toLatin1), [toUtf8()](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.7/qstring.html#toUtf8)

```
const char* data = s->toAscii();  // if you want ASCII encoding
data = s->toUtf8();  // if you want UTF-8 encoding

// etc.
```

Comment: Ah now I see, I tried something like std::cout << s;... Thanks a lot.